# Why isnt redis displaying my results

Tags: node.js, node-redis

Im trying to print out results set in redis. Im using node_redis but I cant seem to check if my key value pair is being set.

Code

```
var app = require("express")();
var http = require("http").Server(app);
var io = require("socket.io")(http);
var redis = require("redis");
var client = redis.createClient();

client.set('framework', 'AngularJS', function(err, reply) {
      console.log(reply);
      client.get('framework', function(err, reply) {
   console.log(reply);
   });
 });
```

I've printed out the client to see if its connected and it says the value is true. I thought at first this was because of asynchronous issues but that doesnt seem to be the case.

Comment: What output are you seeing?

Comment: Nothing is outputting through the node instance i have running on localhost.

Comment: Are you sure you have a Redis server running on `localhost:6379`?

Comment: Do console.log(err) in set and get callbacks and check if there are any errors

Answer (score 0):

You can switch to the `ioredis` package, and the app will successfully print out the result on the console.
Besides, I am afraid your code snippet will not affect the `redis` database, and you will get a `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`. Because the connection process has not been applied.

You should add:

```
client.connect();
```

Before setting the key value.